# $10$ independent observations are chosen at random from an exponential distribution with mean $1$.

Tags: probability

***Problem:*** $10$ independent observations are chosen at random from an exponential
distribution with mean $1$.
Calculate the probability that at least $5$ of them are in the interval $(1, 3)$.

***Thoughts:***
Clearly the length of the interval involved is $2$, but I am not sure how to solve this using the p.d.f of an exponential distribution
$f(x)=1/ \theta e^{\frac {-x}{\theta}}$ . Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: If I tell you the density of something is $\frac{1}{\theta} \mathrm{e}^{-x/\theta}$ and ask you the mass between $x=1$ and $x=3$, how do you get that mass?

Comment: @EricTowers integrate between 1 and 3?

Comment: If the integral of a mass density is a mass, what's the integral of a probability density?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm confused was my answer correct? To answer that I am assuming you mean a probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you find the probability that one observation is on that interval? Once you have that, it becomes your $p$ for a binomial distribution with $n=10$ where you want to find $P(x=5)$.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use properties of sums of independent random variables. Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable of the $i^{th}$ observation in interval $(1,3)$. Then $S_{10} = X_1+X_2 +\cdots + X_{10}$ is also an independent random variable. Then you want to find $P(S_{10} \ge 5)$.

Hint: Using Binomial gives you the rest.